# PHP function that accepts a JSON encoded array

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

I was solving some math matrix problem, and I got idea to write PHP function that accepts a JSON encoded array and:

1) Sort first row of the given matrix (2D array) in ascending order. During the sorting, other rows should be moved like they are sticked to the first row (you are moving all columns when sorting first row).

2) Find the biggest number in the sorted 2D array except of first row. Then calculate the sum of the biggest number's coordinates (coordinates are starting at [1, 1]).

-- First row is only for sorting, it is not used for calculations

-- If the biggest number exist in more than one row then all coordinates of  this biggest number have to be added to the sum)

Example of matrix (2D array) is:

6 3 9

9 1 6

4 7 9

Solution to the example is following:

6 3 9  =>  3 6 9  => 3 6 9

9 1 6  =>  1 9 6  => 1 **9** 6 => 9 (2, 2) and 9 (3, 3) => (2 + 2) + (3 + 3) => 10

4 7 9  =>  7 4 9 =>  7 4 **9**

But, at the moment,I`m beginner in PHP and such code is above my skill, so I need some help.

First part is PHP array, but how to write such array with values found with coordinates as index. As you see, I`m stuck at the beginning of the problem!

Comment: Just like it says: Create a PHP function that accepts a JSON encoded array, sorts first row  in ascending order, second and third row follows columns in first row, then calculate the sum of the biggest number's coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map the sort of the first row to the remaining rows, you can first sort it independently with `asort` to maintain key association:

```
$input = [      // or for PHP < 5.4: $input = array(
    [6,3,9],    //                       array(6,3,9),            
    [9,1,6],    //                       array(9,1,6),
    [4,7,9]     //                       array(4,7,9)
];              //                    );

$sort_keys = $input[0];
asort($sort_keys);
```

Then `use` the sorted array in `array_map` to return a sorted version of your input array.

```
$sorted = array_map(function($row) use ($sort_keys){
    foreach ($sort_keys as $key => $value) {
        $result[] = $row[$key];
    }
    return $result;
}, $input);
```

Comment: Whenever I try to echo $result, i got fatal error.

Comment: `$result` is an array, so you shouldn't be able to echo it, but that should just give you a `Notice: array to string conversion`, not a fatal error. The fatal error is probably because your PHP version is old and doesn't support the [short array syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php##language.types.array.syntax). Keep in mind that this is only to solve the first part of your problem where you said you were stuck.

Comment: I tried to work on the rest, but mainly just ideas I don`t know how to implement in code, so if you can help me with the rest, I`ll be grateful!

I figured it would output that array already sorted when I try to echo.

Comment: It gave me `Notice: array to string conversion`  when i wrote `echo $input;`,
but I tried with this code too `echo $result[];`, then it gave me fatal error.
I have PHP version 5.5.35 / 5.6.21 / 7.0.6, using XAMPP.

I˙m still learning basics in PHP, I realize this idea is beyond my current knowledge in programming, but it`s good way to learn something from someone.

Comment: Oh yeah, `echo $result[];` definitely will give a fatal error. If you want to see the contents of the array before and after sorting, you can use `var_dump` or `print_r`. [Here is a link to a working example](https://3v4l.org/ClZRo).

Comment: Thanks, that cleared some confusion! I˙ll try to output it thorugh HTML table with foreach loop, to get some graphical representation.

Comment: When I want to see content of array through `var_dump` or `print_r` on my local env using xampp, the content is shown in one line.

Like this:
input array: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 3 [2] => 9 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => 1 [2] => 6 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 7 [2] => 9 ) ) sorted array: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 6 [2] => 9 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 9 [2] => 6 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 4 [2] => 9 ) )

I copied your code, nothing was added, and I tried with `<br>` code but it stays the same.

Comment: @Bengall If you install xdebug (which you should do anyway), `var_dump` will give you a nicely formatted output with line breaks. I don't think I can be much help with getting xdebug working in xampp, but I know there are various articles out there to get you started.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I˙ll do that.